# How to fix undefined array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am fairly new to javascript so any assistance is appreciated. I am trying to collect 2 related inputs from a user and display the array object as a table. When the inputs are submitted however, the array is displaying as undefined. I am not sure where I am going wrong. Any suggestions?

I have tried different methods of collecting the inputs off the form but none seem to work.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Example:</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

var flights = [];

  function add(ele) {  
      flights.push(number, miles);
      render();
      document.getElementById("number").value = "";
      document.getElementById("miles").value = "";
  }
  function render() {

      document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = "";
         thelisthtml = "";
         for(i = 0; i< flights.length; i++)
         thelisthtml += "<div class='card' id="+ i +"><div class='card-body'>";
         thelisthtml += "Flight  " + (i+1) + " : " + flights[i]  + "         " + "<button type='submit' onclick = 'clearToDo(this)' id="+ i +">Remove From List</button>";

      document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = thelisthtml; 
     }

function calculateStatus(){

    var totalMiles = Number(document.getElementById("totalMiles").value);

     if (miles < 9999){
             tr = document.getElementById("table").rows[1];
                tr.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
            }

            if (miles >= 10000 && miles <= 24999){
            tr = document.getElementById("table").rows[2];
            tr.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
            }

            if (miles >= 25000){
            tr = document.getElementById("table").rows[3];
            tr.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
            }                                   
}

function refreshPage() {
    window.location.reload();
} 

  </script>

</head>
<body>

<br>
    <table id="table" border ="1">
 <tr>
 <th>Medallion Status</th>
 <th>Level</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Bronze</td>
<td> < 10000 miles</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Silver</td>
 <td> < 25000 miles</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Gold</td>
 <td> > 25000</td>
 </tr>
  </table>  

   <h1><strong>Traveler Information </strong></h1><br> <br>
  Flight Number: <input type="text" id="number" name="number" value="" /> 
   <br> <br>
  Miles Flown: <input type="text" id="miles" name="miles" value=""/> <br> 
  <br>
   <input type="submit" value="Add Flight" id="go" onclick="add(this)"/>
    <p>----------------------------</p>
    <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Flight</th>
    <th>Miles</th>
  </tr>
   <thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="col-md-6" id="mydiv"></tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
     <input type="reset" id="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" 
     onclick="refreshPage()" /> <br> <br> <br> 
   <br> <br> 

   </body>
  </html>
```

the expected result is the array will display in a table as the user enters information. the actual result is the array is undefined.

Comment: You're pushing two variables to the flights array in the add method. Where are you setting those variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues but the answer to your question about how to fix the `flights` array containing `undefined` is to change

```
function add(ele) {  
  flights.push(number, miles);
  render();
  document.getElementById("number").value = "";
  document.getElementById("miles").value = "";
}
```

to

```
function add() {
    const numberElem = document.getElementById("number");
    const milesElem = document.getElementById("miles");
    flights.push(numberElem.value, milesElem.value);
    render();
    numberElem.value = "";
    milesElem.value = "";
}
```

In your original `add` function you are pushing `number` and `miles` onto the `flights` array but `number` and `miles` are undefined variables so you are pushing `undefined` and `undefined` onto the `flights` array.

---

To also fix the other issues I'd suggest replacing your `add` and `render` functions with the follow

```
function add() {
  const numberElem = document.getElementById("number");
  const milesElem = document.getElementById("miles");
  flights.push({
    number: numberElem.value,
    miles: milesElem.value});
  render();
  numberElem.value = "";
  milesElem.value = "";
}

function render() {
  const tbody = document.querySelector('#outputTable tbody');
  tbody.innerHTML = flights.map((flight, i) => {
    return ''
      + '<tr>'
      +   '<td>'
      +     flight.number
      +   '</td>'
      +   '<td>'
      +     flight.miles
      +   '</td>'
      +   '<td>'
      +     `<button type='button' onclick="clearToDo(${i})">`
      +       'Remove From List'
      +     '</button>'
      +   '</td>'
      + '</tr>';
  }).join('');
}
```

and changing your second `<table>` to `<table id="outputTable">`.

Comment: I noticed the variables not initialized error after I posted, but I didnt see the other errors. It makes perfect sense when I look at it like this. Rocky thank you. I really appreciate the tips.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help : )